# App running on background (Phonegap Cordova 3.0)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing with Cordova 3.x an app that need to runs on background when you press the HOME button, on Android I have in my config.xml the following line:

```
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
```

This works well on my Android emulator, when I press HOME button the apps continues on background but when I test on my real device the apps only runs on background too few seconds...

Any Solution? Thanks! :-)

Comment: PG Build docs say that preference is iOS only. @gazapko, did you find an Android solution?

Comment: Have you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The preference `exit-on-suspend` is only supported by iOS. According to a PhoneGap developer:

> We worked on this a little while ago, but unfortunately because of
>   nature of Android Activities, exiting on suspend breaks various
>   functionalities that use additional activities. For example, when you
>   use navigator.camera.getPicture, when the camera activity is launched,
>   the app's main Activity is suspended, which will exit if we're exiting
>   on suspend.

A possible option is listening to the `pause` event and then exiting the app when it occurs:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script>
  function onPause() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
  };

  function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
  };

  function onLoad() {
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", lbmon.onDeviceReady, false);
  };
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">
</body>
```